# Unknown sized cascaded dropdownlist in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this problem:

```
MVC4
RAZOR VIEW ENGINE
    RESTful services
    - GetCategoriesBySiteId: This method get a JSON with a list of categories
    - GetChildCategoriesByParent: This method get a JSON with a list of child categories by a parent id category
```

My problem is that i dont know the deep of the categories and his children.

What i need to do is cascade this dropdownlist's that the user selects and the only category that the form must accept is the last child of the categories tree that the user has selected.

How can i perform this in MVC4 with Razor view engine?

Comment: You can populate the dropdowns using ajax. Have you tried that?

Comment: I dont know how to do it when i dont know the deep of the cascading dropdonws... i did it with a fixed size of childs but this is not the case.